# Is Nhibernate Vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Just wanted to know if there is a big chance to inject SQL While using nhibernate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using the criteria generators then no. nHibernate is aware of the .Net types and is consequently able to handle all escaping for you when generating queries.

Unparameterized HQL is vulnerable however.